# Finding the next location in a grid

Tags: java, algorithm

I am creating a method to help me find the next position in a grid of islands/objects in a 3d world(but ignoreing the Y coordinate for now), they have a distance of 200 for each island(islandDistance).

What I currently have is this:

```
public static Location findLocation(String latest,String server) {
    if (latest == null) {
        latest = sql.findLatestIslandEntry(server);
        if (latest != null && latest.isEmpty()) // first creation
            latest = "0,4,0";
        else if (latest == null)
            return null;
    }
    String split[] = latest.split(",");
    List<String> locationString = Arrays.asList(split);
    List<Double> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String xyz : locationString) {
        locations.add(Double.valueOf(xyz));
    }

    String world = CC.getSTDConfig().getString("worldname");
    Location l = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(world),0,4,0);
    if (locations.get(0) <= 0) {
        l.setX(Math.abs(locations.get(0)) + islandDistance);
    } else {
        l.setX(0 - locations.get(0));
    }
    if (locations.get(2) <= 0) {
        l.setZ(Math.abs(locations.get(2)) + islandDistance);
    } else {
        l.setZ(0 - locations.get(2));
    }
    return l;
}
```

Even before testing I could see that this wouldn't work. I would end always adding to both x and z when thats not always what I want. I made an example of the dataset I want as output here: [image: picture]

Basicly what I want to is to get the next position depending on how many I have already inserted and maybe the last one inserted ? thats the info I use in my code currently atleast. Say I just inserted island number 25 and now want island 26 I should get the result 0,600(the order can be different I just want to fill the grid out)

Comment: Which is the *order* for positions, so as to understand what "next" means?

Comment: So the order would be 0,0 -> 0,200 -> 0,-200 ->200,0 -> -200,0 -> 200,200 ->200,-200 -> -200,-200 -> 0,400 and so on

Answer (score 0):

You want to generate integer coordinates ordered by Euclidean distance. To diminish calculation, it is enough to generate coordinates in the first octant (for 2d case), so X and Y are non-negative and Y<=X. For every calculated `(X,Y)`pair just generate also `(X,-Y), (-X,Y), (-X,-Y),(Y,X),(Y,-X), (-Y,X), (-Y,-X)` (except for zero components).

Create priority queue where comparison key is sum of squares (squared distance `X*X+Y*Y`). Push (0,0) item. At every step extract minimum item `(MX, MY)` and push next points

```
Output MX, MY and all permutations
if (MY = 0) and (MX < SomeBorderValue)
     push (MX+1, 0) 
if MY < MX 
     push (MX, MY+1)
```